Conditional parameter spec for hyperparameter tuning for logistic regression
How to configure conditonalparameterspec for the below code where, when penalty is l2 solver should be 'sag' and when penalty is 'l1', solver should be 'saga'.
from google.cloud.aiplatform import hyperparameter_tuning as hpt

worker_pool_specs = [
        {
            "machine_spec": {
                "machine_type": "n1-standard-4",
                "accelerator_type": "NVIDIA_TESLA_K80",
                "accelerator_count": 1,
            },
            "replica_count": 1,
            "container_spec": {
                "image_uri": container_image_uri,
                "command": [],
                "args": [],
            },
        }
    ]

custom_job = aiplatform.CustomJob(
    display_name='my_job',
    worker_pool_specs=worker_pool_specs,
    labels={'my_key': 'my_value'},
)


hp_job = aiplatform.HyperparameterTuningJob(
    display_name='hp-test',
    custom_job=job,
    metric_spec={
        'loss': 'minimize',
    },
    parameter_spec={
        'C': hpt.DoubleParameterSpec(min=0.001, max=0.1, scale='log'),
        'max_iter': hpt.IntegerParameterSpec(min=4, max=128, scale='linear'),
        'penalty': hpt.CategoricalParameterSpec(values=['l1', 'l2']),
        'solver': hpt.CategoricalParameterSpec(values=['sag', 'saga'])
    },
    max_trial_count=128,
    parallel_trial_count=8,
    labels={'my_key': 'my_value'},
    )

hp_job.run()

print(hp_job.trials)

I have looked into documentations and have tried asking help from GPTs but am not able to figgure it out. Could you guys help?

Hi , could you please share the error message that you are getting ?

In your code you can do some troubleshooting like -
You should initialize the project and region using the below format documented here .
def create_hyperparameter_tuning_job_sample(
    project: str,
    location: str,
    staging_bucket: str,
    display_name: str,
    container_uri: str,
):
    aiplatform.init(project=project, location=location, staging_bucket=staging_bucket)


container_image_uri in youe code - check that setup is a valid Docker image .

For detailed investigation you can create a public issue tracker describing your issue  and vote [+1] and Eng team will look on the issue .
